i cannot insert data into my postgreSQL db with Prisma Orm
i am working on a next.js web application. i am using vercel, postgreSQL and prisma. this is my prisma schema:
model entry {
  no Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  content String
  cretedAt DateTime @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(0)
  authorName String  @db.VarChar(255)
  baslikName String
  baslik baslik @relation(fields: [baslikName], references: [title], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
}

model baslik {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  title String @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  entries entry[]
}

there are topics called basliks and the users are supposed to submit entries to these  baskliks.
baslik page has a submission form to submit entry to that baslik. this the code for baslik/page.js:
"use client"
import ClientComponent from "@/app/baslik/client-component";
import {useSearchParams} from "next/navigation";

export default function Page() {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()
    const id = searchParams.get("id")// i use this searchParam to pick the spesific baslik 

    return (
        <div>
            <ClientComponent id={id} />
        </div>
    );
}


this is client component:
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import fetchBaslik from "@/app/baslik/server-component";
import Entry from "@/app/components/entry";
import styles from "./baslik.css";
import InputForm from "@/app/input/inputForm";

export default function ClientComponent({ id }) {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [entries, setEntries] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getBaslik() {
            const result = await fetchBaslik(id);
            setTitle(result.title);
            setEntries(result.entries);
        }

        if (id) {
            getBaslik();
        }
    }, [id]);

    return (
        <div className={"baslik-main"}>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            {entries.map(e => (
                <Entry content={e.content} author={e.authorName} key={e.no}/>
            ))}
            <InputForm baslikName={title}/>
        </div>
    );
}


server component:
"use server";
import { db } from "@/app/lib/prisdb";

export default async function fetchBaslik(id) {
    const baslik = await db.baslik.findUnique({
        where: {
            id: Number(id)
        },
        include: {
            entries: {
                select: {
                    content: true,
                    authorName: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Ensure the result is a plain JSON object
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(baslik));
}


input form:
// InputForm.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "./inputForm.css"
const InputForm = ({ baslikName }) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    const [nick, setNick] = useState('');
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const response = await fetch('/api/addEntry', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ content: text, authorName: nick, baslikName: baslikName }),
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Failed to add entry');
            }

            const result = await response.json();
            setMessage('Entry added successfully');
            setText('');
            setNick('');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error adding entry:', error);
            setMessage('An error occurred');
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="form-container">
            <form className="entry-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <textarea
                    className="text-input"
                    value={text}
                    onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Entry"
                    rows={4}
                    cols={15}
                    required
                />
                <textarea
                    className="nick-input"
                    value={nick}
                    onChange={(e) => setNick(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Nick"
                    rows={2}
                    cols={15}
                    required
                />
                <button type="submit" className="submit-button">Submit</button>
            </form>
            {message && <p>{message}</p>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default InputForm;


and addEntry file inside app/pages/api directory:
// pages/api/addEntry.js

import { db } from "@/app/lib/prisdb";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        // Handle POST request
        const { content, authorName, baslikName } = req.body;

        // Validate required fields
        if (!content || !authorName || !baslikName) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Content, Author Name, and Baslik Name are required' });
        }

        try {
            // Create new entry in the database
            const newEntry = await db.entry.create({
                data: {
                    content: content,
                    authorName: authorName,
                    baslikName: baslikName,
                },
            });

            // Respond with the new entry
            return res.status(200).json(newEntry);
        } catch (error) {
            // Handle database errors
            console.error('Error adding entry:', error.message);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to add entry' });
        }
    } else {
        // Handle other HTTP methods
        res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
        res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
    }
}


when you try to submit an entry to a baslik using input the input form, it doesn't work. but i really can't say which part of my code causes it. did i build the app wrong or i used wrong a file url? i'd really appreciate if you could help
